# Why conics is the "perfect" shape of lenses?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

It is stated on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspheric_lens#Surface_profile) that we have the following formula
$$
z = \frac{r^2}{R\left(1+ \sqrt{1-(1+\kappa)r^2/R^2}\right)} + \text{ (higher order terms)}
$$
for the usual shape of an aspheric lens. The first term is a conics.

It is also stated in the answer by Colin K (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/869/colin-k), Aspherical lenses - perfect analytical shape, URL (version: 2011-01-10): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2683) that to focus a collimated beam of light, the ideal shape would be using different conics on two sides of the lens. **How do I prove this fact? A derivation would be very helpful.**

Is conics the only choice? Are there any other reasons why conics are good for lens? Does there exists other ideal shapes?

Answer (score 0):

The "ideal shape" of a mirror, for reference, is a parabola.  It's easy to show that rays parallel to the parabola's axis all reflect to the focus.  However, off-axis rays will be distorted, which is why a spherical mirror is usually selected because a sphere "looks almost like" a parabola for all incident ray angles.

When it comes to a refractive lens, a similar ray-trace analysis will show how, say, a plano-hyperbola or a hyperbola-plano, etc. lens will perform.   Don't get distracted by your referenced answer's dive into diffraction limit as that's not what you're asking here.  I will second the recommendation to read Smith's Optical Engineering to learn first how  sphere-sphere lenses of different positive/negative combinations perform.